# How can you interact with a running SPL application?

Tags: infosphere-spl

How can I interact with my running SPL application?  E.g., if I want it to start or stop collecting certain stats, or if I want it to stop Export-ing certain properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SPL, think about a stream whenever you need to send a message/data.

Create an input stream using a `*Source` operator (e.g., `FileSource` or `UDPSource`).  When you want to interact with your running SPL application, send a message via that input source.  The input stream operator will then send the message to a separate "parser" operator that can then act on the message.